# How could I display multiple of the same image using iteration in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I have tried displaying the same image, it should be able to display 10 of the same picture and I was also wondering where could use the pady and padx to space the pictures out.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
        for img in range(10):
            canvas = Canvas(self.frame, width=30, height=30)
            canvas.pack()
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("DicePic.jpeg"))
            canvas.create_image(50, 50, anchor=NW, image=img)
            self.frame.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: You never use `self.dicePic` in any image container, like `Label` or `Canvas`, so no image will be shown.  Another issue is that you use same instance variable `self.dicePic` for the ten instances of `PhotoImage()`.

Comment: Ok, I tried fixing my code but it still won't display the picture

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `mainloop` inside a loop. `mainloop` itself is a loop, as the name implies.

Comment: Also the size of the canvas is 30x30 pixels, but you put the image at `(50, 50)` which is outside of the viewable area of the canvas.  You should only create one canvas for all the images at different locations instead of one canvas per image.

Comment: Also move the `img = ...` outside of the loop. That way you will only have 1 `ImageTk` object to worry about.